# Checkmarx Resource Exhaustion in Golang url.Parse

Tags: go, security, checkmarx, denial-of-service

I'm getting *Checkmarx* issue:

> The resource Parse allocated by **FUNCTION_X** in the file **FILE** at line **LINE** is prone to resource exhaustion when used by **FUNCTION_Y** in the file **FILE** at line **LINE**.

I can see that data from `Parse` result is processed in a loop, so I added a length check before the loop, sth like this:

```golang
if len(query) > 100 {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("too many query params [%d]", len(query))
}
for k := range query {
    // ...
}
```

But *Checkmarx* is still complaining. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I know nothing about Checkmarx, but if it complains about url.Parse then validating afterwards doesn't help, of course.

Comment: I also added a length check before `url.Parse` but it doesn't help too

Answer (score 1):

Having looked into it, it’s not about `url.parse`, it is about passing user inputs to a loop controlled by `len()`.

Your code is fine, and Checkmarx SAST needs to understand that `len()` is the size/length function for Go.

You should mark this as *Not Exploitable* and report it as *False Positive* to *Checkmarx*.

Comment: Hi friend :-) I removed the "A bug was opened and will be fixed in future versions."